# Using jQuery in Zombie.js

Tags: jquery, zombie.js

I realize there are other libraries designed for the use of jQuery-like syntax with Zombie, but for my purposes, I specifically want/need to use jQuery itself in order to maintain compatibility with some earlier-written code.

I installed the npm jQuery package, and I've been trying to import jQuery into my script and then initialize it with the window returned by Zombie like so:

```
var Zombie= require("zombie"),
$ = require("jquery")
, zombie = new Zombie();

zombie.visit("http://www.mysite.com", function (err, browser, status) {
  if(err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err);
  }

  //Initialize a new jQuery instance with the current window returned by Zombie
  var $window = $(browser.window);
  //Get an actual jQuery object so we can search for stuff
  var document = $window("body");

  var inputBoxUsername = document.find("input#username");

  console.log(inputBoxUsername.html());
});
```

This isn't working, as it says that there's no `html()` function, and jQuery doesn't actually seem to be returning the object I'm expecting.

Is there a way to use jQuery with Zombie?

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: Sorry, I failed at editing. It was supposed to be `document`.

Answer (score 3):

If your site is already loading jquery, you can use the loaded jQuery straight away, which in some cases is far easier.

```
var document = browser.window.$("body");
```

Will work as expected, since it is a jQuery object.

I think that you can add script files anyway so you could dinamically add jQuery and use it as I just mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the page you are working with doesn't include jQuery, and you are only retrieving data, then try using Cheerio on top of Zombie:

```
zombie.visit("http://example.com", function () {
  var $ = cheerio.load(browser.html());
  console.log($('title').text());
}
```

Comment: Best possible implementation!