# jQuery AJAX Get Callback Only Called Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this problem where the jQuery `get` function inside my `updateMyApps` isn't being called correctly. I call the function right after declaring it and that works perfectly. It loops through the data and appends the elements to the DOM.

But when I submit the form `#addapplicationform` it runs the jQuery post function which works correctly but the `updateMyApps` function doesn't seem to be working correctly when that happens.

The `console.log("Test");` always seems to get called. Even when submitting the form. But for some reason the callback function for that get request only gets called that one time on page load.

```
<script>
function updateMyApps() {
    console.log("Test"); //Always works
    $.get("/api/clients", function(data) {
        console.log(data); //Works first time
        $("#myapps").html("<h4>My Applications</h4>");
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            var element = '<div>' + item.name + '</div>' + '<div>' + item.id + '</div>' + '<div>' + item.secret + '</div>' + '<a href="/edit"><input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary form-control" value="Edit" style="width: 100px;"></a>';
            $("#myapps").append(element);
        });
    });
}
updateMyApps(); // Works perfectly

$("#addapplicationform").submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post("/api/clients", $( "#addapplicationform" ).serialize(), function () {
    updateMyApps(); //Doesn't work
  });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas on why the get request callback is only firing once?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention this. It looks like the GET `/api/clients` only is getting called on page load. When submitting the form it isn't even hitting my back end at all.

**EDIT 2**

Realized this was a caching issue. Adding `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });` seems to have fixed the issue. Also marked the question as duplicate of where I found that code snippet.

Comment: Did you check that you are not getting any errors on the server side? Does the $.get gets fired on the console in the network tab?

Comment: Doesn't even look like it's hitting my server.

Comment: try this and check if the fail handler gets fired...                            $.get("/api/clients", function(data) { }).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  });

Comment: The `.fail` function isn't even being called.

Comment: try to check if at least this is really being called                    $.get("/api/clients", function(data) { }).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  }).always(function() {
    alert( "I am getting called" );
  });

Comment: @revobtz Nope. The `always` function only gets called on page load. Not when submitting the form.

Comment: How did you confirm that `updateMyApps()` is only called once? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 `updateMyApps()` is called multiple times. Once when page is loaded and whenever I submit the form. I know that because `console.log("Test");` gets called on page load and when I submit the form. BUT `console.log(data);` only gets called on page load not when I submit the form.

Comment: This only makes me think that for some reason the submit handler is not being called when your are submitting the form. try to paste the full source code of the form.

Comment: @revobtz - it clearly is being called as the `console.log("Test")` is apparently being run

Comment: @CharlieFish can you reproduce issue at jsfiddle? Is `/api/clients` expecting both `GET` and `POST` requests?

Comment: which version of jQuery are you loading - I only ask because it may be some bug in that version of jQuery where calling a jquery ajax function within the callback of another jquery ajax function may be broken in that specific version of jquery - I've never heard of such a bug it's one avenue to explore

Comment: @guest271314 - `Is /api/clients expecting both GET and POST requests` - if you read the question, you'll see BOTH work, it's just that the GET doesn't work on submit

Comment: @guest271314 `/api/clients` does have both GET and POST options. And not sure how I could do it on JSFiddle since it requires a backend.

Comment: @JaromandaX jQuery Version 1.11.3. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js

Comment: @CharlieFish have you tried the latest 1.x version? 1.12.4 - not sure if any changes from 1.11.x -> 1.12.x would break any other code, just a suggestion

Comment: also look at using http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/ - maybe that will fire with useful information

Comment: @CharlieFish You can mock an ajax response at stacksnippets, jsfiddle or plnkr. See [Does Stack Overflow have an “echo page” to test AJAX requests, inside a code snippet?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288902/does-stack-overflow-have-an-echo-page-to-test-ajax-requests-inside-a-code-sni/290948#290948) , jsfiddle [docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html)

Comment: @JaromandaX I've been using the older version due to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806763/zombie-js-jquery-load-error-j-getclientrects-is-not-a-function) issue.

Comment: WOW so strange. I just started using this proxy/vpn thing because StackOverflow was giving me an error about my IP rate limiting. For whatever reason it now seems to be working. Only thing I changed in my code is added the ajaxerror which never got fired but it just started working. Makes 0 sense to me.

Comment: An unhandled `Promise` rejection?

Comment: @guest271314 No idea. Kinda over my head at this point haha.

Comment: Is error handler called?

Comment: @guest271314 Nope.

Comment: Well, if Question is resolved, you can post and accept your own Answer, or close Question? Not sure how users viewing Question can reproduce issue? Not a suggestion, only a possible consideration.

Comment: Hmm. I will probably close the question. I don't really have an answer to provide. One last question tho. It seems to work when I disable caching in my browser. But when I have caching enabled it fails and doesn't update. Even tho the content has changed. Any ideas on why that might be happening? That would be the answer if I could figure it out.

Comment: I don't know which server side language but if php try this: header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT"); This will disable cache on all web browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a console.log in your submit....

```
<script>
function updateMyApps() {
    console.log("Test"); //Always works
    $.get("/api/clients", function(data) {
        console.log(data); //Works first time
        $("#myapps").html("<h4>My Applications</h4>");
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            var element = '<div>' + item.name + '</div>' + '<div>' + item.id + '</div>' + '<div>' + item.secret + '</div>' + '<a href="/edit"><input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary form-control" value="Edit" style="width: 100px;"></a>';
            $("#myapps").append(element);
        });
    });
}
updateMyApps(); // Works perfectly

$("#addapplicationform").submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("works!!!"); // <-- add this console.log
  $.post("/api/clients", $( "#addapplicationform" ).serialize(), function () {
    updateMyApps(); //Doesn't work
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes that console.log works. But that doesn't answer my question. The `get` callback function inside of `updateMyApps` still isn't getting called.

Comment: I just trying to see your error...And for debugging what if you add a console.log() inside your $.post ? Does it works?

Comment: Yes. The post gets called. And the `updateMyApps` gets called. The `console.log("Test");` gets called every time. But the `get` callback only gets called once instead of twice. It should get called on page load and on form submit.